# How to make WordPress RTL support for theme developer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently, I'm building a WordPress template from scratch and everything is perfect, now I want to add RTL support to my theme and make it ready to add Arabic content for the RTL version.
I'm using advanced custom fields to add/update my website content. What is the best way to achieve this as a developer?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way, you can change the WordPress back and frontend language, log in the wp-admin panel > Settings > General. There change the Site Language option to your desired language.

Or if you want only in front side then please check below details.

Adding support for language written in a Right-To-Left (RTL) direction is easy.

There are two ways to do that:

1. By creating a fully mirror of your style.css file named style-rtl.css
2. By overwriting all the horizontal positioning attributes of your CSS
   stylesheet in a separate stylesheet file named rtl.css.

For more details here I have shared the WordPress official document for reference.
[Right to left language support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Right_to_Left_Language_Support). I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I'm focusing on the front end, not the backend. I understand that we need to use RTL style and I already have it but how I can make allow visitors to change the website language to Arabic and the RTL style will be applied based on the selected language.do I want to use the WPML plugin or I can do this without third-party plugins?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Nafei
Yes, it is possible without a plugin but it is a lengthy and time-consuming process.
Better to use WPML plugin its full fill your whole requirement.